# Vue/Vite won't find my custom package when I import it locally

Tags: typescript, vue.js, npm, vite, package.json

I'm trying to create a custom package to my project and import it via `npm` locally.

I'm using `vite-plugin-dts` to make my `.d.ts` files, but when I import my component to use in my Vue file, I keep getting

```
[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to resolve import "chat-bot-prototype" from "src/views/agents/AgentDialogues.vue". Does the file exist?
```

This is my `index.d.ts` in `chat-bot-prototype/dist`:

```
import { AllowedComponentProps } from 'vue';
import { ComponentCustomProps } from 'vue';
import { ComponentOptionsMixin } from 'vue';
import { DefineComponent } from 'vue';
import { ExtractPropTypes } from 'vue';
import { VNodeProps } from 'vue';

export declare const ChatScreen: DefineComponent<{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, ComponentOptionsMixin, ComponentOptionsMixin, {}, string, VNodeProps & AllowedComponentProps & ComponentCustomProps, Readonly<ExtractPropTypes<{}>>, {}, {}>;

export { }
```

My project's `package.json` import looks like `"chat-bot-prototype": "file:../chat-bot-prototype"` and my Vue file's import looks like `import { ChatScreen } from 'chat-bot-prototype'`.

What am I missing here?

Edit: this is my module's `package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "chat-bot-prototype",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "files": [
        "dist"
    ],
    "main": "./dist/chat-bot-prototype.umd.js",
    "module": "./dist/chat-bot-prototype.mjs",
    "exports": {
        ".": {
            "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
            "import": "./dist/chat-bot-prototype.mjs",
            "require": "./dist/chat-bot-prototype.umd.js"
        },
        "./style.css": "./dist/style.css",
        "./dist/*": "./dist/*",
        "./package.json": "./package.json"
    },
    "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "vite build"
    },
    "dependencies": { ... },
    "devDependencies": { ... }

}
```

Comment: You can start with checking there's chat-bot-prototype in node_modules. Then it needs to be verified its package.json is ok

Comment: Any tips on what to check?

Comment: "main", "types", etc entries should be valid. If the problem persists, please, provide a way to reproduce. It's specific to your case and cannot be solved in general

Comment: I added my `package.json` in the question

Comment: It should work. Make sure that node_modules/chat-bot-prototype/dist/chat-bot-prototype.mjs really exists in your project

Comment: I published into npm and it worked. It doesn't work locally. Vite is not working.

Comment: It especially matters what happens inside node_modules. It doesn't matter if it's file: or something else. There are several scenarios that could make it fail for you, and it's unknown which one it is. Could be a problem with vite and symbolic links (they are usually created by file:), or you didn't install deps properly, or else. You didn't confirm that node_modules/chat-bot-prototype/dist/chat-bot-prototype.mjs  file exists in the project.   Please, provide a way to reproduce

Comment: Agreed! It really seems that everything is fine because in the first version I uploaded to npm and it was saying that my exports were wrong. I fixed it, changed to the version you're seeing in the original question and now I can use it with `npm install chat-bot-prototype`. IMO this is the proof that everything is fine and Vite is struggling to make things work. edit: also, the file does exists.

Comment: The proof that is required is to isolate the problem. Considering that local and npm versions are identical, the only relevant difference this would be that node_module/chat-bot-prototype is a link to ../chat-bot-prototype, not a regular folder. This can affect module resolution in theory, but I'm unaware of such problem in vite. This can be confirmed by deleting node_module/chat-bot-prototype and copying ../chat-bot-prototype to the same location manually. If this makes vite work then that's it